# How to sync iphone

Tags: 16.04, iphone, itunes

Is there any way to sync **iphone** in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Please help!

Comment: Install Windows in a virtual machine, then install iTunes in that, and hook up your device to the VM via USB passthrough.  No other *working* way to sync an iPhone from Linux though.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to synch your iPhone using Ubuntu (though it will vary since apple tends to break the open source tools with updates) and no you can not install iTunes on Ubuntu.  Both questions answered but your really need to improve your question. I really doubt this is what you want to ask.

Comment: Actuallly i want to fully depend on linux. I uninstalled Windows from my laptop.

Comment: @Rinzwind How can you sync?

Comment: Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0b7zfvmxPvA  But I agree with Thomas: Apple does not want you to synch from Ubuntu. So get a better supported device (any android would do ...) or use Windows/Mac OS from a virtual machine.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but whenever I see the term "sync" I immediately ask "from what to what? " You've only identified one side of the equation, leaving us to guess the other side. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask then [edit] your post to explain in further detail exactly what you want. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score -1):

I've found all this information in this website: http://geeknizer.com/sync-iphone-linux/

Maybe you can try this:

> Step 1. Add Repository:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
> ```
>
> and Update the Apt source list
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Step 2. Next, we install all the required packages:
>
> `sudo apt-get install gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse libgvfscommon0 ifuse libgpod-dev libgpod-common libiphone-utils libiphone0 python-iphone libplist++1 libplist-utils python-plist libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev libusbmuxd1 usbmuxd`
>
> Step 3. Let’s Configure Fuse, our interfacing component.  Edit fuse.conf file
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /etc/fuse.conf
> ```
>
> Change
>
> ```
> #user_allow_other
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> user_allow_other
> ```
>
> Save and exit.
>
> Step 4. Next, We modify your user for Fuse so that it can Auto-mount iPhone/iPod Touch on every boot.
>
> Navigate to “System” -> “Administration” -> “Users and Groups”, click on the little key at bottom to unlock it for making changes. Then, select your username (`<fx>` for me) and click on “Manage Groups”.
>
> Lookout for “fuse” group, double-click  it. Tick the checkbox next to your name in the new popup window. Click on OK and close all dialogs. You’re now in the “fuse” group.
>
> Step 5. Alright, now log out and in again (Reboot is always better)
>
> When you are back into the session, mount the phone as:
>
> ```
> $ ifuse /mnt/ipod/
> ```
>
> We can also unmount using the following command
>
> ```
> $ fusermount -u /mnt/ipod/
> ```
>
> Step 6. Let’s prepare ipod itunes directory:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir /mnt/ipod/iTunes_Control/Device/
> ```
>
> Fetch your UUID (The first number, 40 characters long)
>
> ```
> $ lsusb -v | grep -i iSerial
> ```
>
> Then, run:
>
> ```
> $ ipod-read-sysinfo-extended
> ```
>
> [mountpoint here is /mnt/ipod/]
>
> This should generate a file named iTunes_Control/Device/SysInfoExtended.
>
> Make sure it’s not empty and should be a big plist (XML file) with a bunch of info.
>
> ```
> $ fusermount -u /mnt/ipod/
> ```
>
> Reboot.
>
> Step 7. Hold your breath and Plug the iPod/iPhone, you should see it appear on the desktop and it should now be:
>
> - Mounted as-is in Rhythmbox and you can add music files. (it can be slow)
> - Mounted in gtkpod but you’ll have to launch the “ifuse /mnt/ipod”.
>
> *Rhyhmbox is unable to remove music files, use the gtkpod to remove files or add videos to the iPhone.

Read more:

- http://geeknizer.com/sync-iphone-linux/#ixzz4tWIRWSuo
- [gtkpod on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkpod/)

Comment: Please review my edits to your post. I added a link to gtkpod as it appeared to be missing. If (as it appears) your solution requires it, it would be good practice to explain that piece further for those who aren't as familiar with the topic as you. Thank you!

Comment: This is totally outdated.